# Python issue with Matplotlib version when reloaded/replot a figure saved with Pickle

Tags: python, matplotlib, version, pickle

I'm facing a version issue with Matplotlib.
I have a code that permits to reload a figure saved with Pickle, and to redraw it in a new window.
However, since an upgrade of Matplotlib to the 2.0 version, I cannot reload figures that were saved with Matplotlib v1.5.

here the issue line: 
`C:\Anaconda36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py:1431: UserWarning: This figure was saved with matplotlib version 1.5.3 and is unlikely to function correctly.
  (version, ))`

I'm wondering if it exists a workaround to still reload a figure saved with a previous version of Matplotlib on the newest version of Matplotlib?

### update

the error I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Reloadfigure.py", line 90, in loaddatapickle
self.figure = pickle.load(filehandler )
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: The "issue" is only a warning. The interesting information would be if the figure can actually be loaded and displayed or in what way this fails.